# Assign Column where equal to value - pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, where-clause

I am trying to `assign` values in a `pandas` `df`. Specifically, for the `df` below I want to use `Column['On']` to determine how many values are currently occurring. I then want to assign these values in groups of `3`. So values;

```
1-3 = 1
4-6 = 2
7-9 = 3 etc
```

This can go up to 20-30 values. I considered np.where but it's not very efficient and I'm returning an error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = ({                
    'On' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],                                     
      })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

This call works:

```
df['P'] = np.where(df['On'] == 1, df['On'],1)
```

But If I want to apply this to other values I get an error:

```
df = df['P'] = np.where(df['On'] == 1, df['On'],1)
df = df['P'] = np.where(df['On'] == 2, df['On'],1)
df = df['P'] = np.where(df['On'] == 3, df['On'],1)

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Comment: Have a look at np.where instead of use the conditional.

Comment: Your initial description of the mapping is ambiguous. Does the value `3` map to group `1` or group `2`? Does `6` belong with `2` or `3`?

Comment: @G.Anderson, sorry. This has been amended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Series masks and `loc`

```py
df['P'] = float('nan')
df['P'].loc[(df['On'] >= 1) & (df['On'] <= 3)] = 1
df['P'].loc[(df['On'] >= 4) & (df['On'] <= 6)] = 2
# ...etc
```

It's pretty easy to extend this with a loop

```py
j = 1
for i in range(1, 20):
    df['P'].loc[(df['On'] >= j) & (df['On'] <= (j+2))] = i
    j += 3
```

Answer (score 1):

With some basic math and vectorization you could achieve better performances.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
n = 1000 
df = pd.DataFrame({"On":np.random.randint(1,20, n)})
```

AlexG's solution

```
%%time
j = 1
df["P"] =  np.nan
for i in range(1, 20):
    df['P'].loc[(df['On'] >= j) & (df['On'] <= (j+2))] = i
    j += 3

CPU times: user 2.11 s, sys: 0 ns, total: 2.11 s
Wall time: 2.11 s
```

Suggested solution

```
%%time
df["P"] = np.ceil(df["On"]/3)


CPU times: user 2.48 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 2.48 ms
Wall time: 2.15 ms
```

The speedup is ~1000x